# How to configure Dockerfile for non-root user but give them access privileges to write to a file in the root dir?

Tags: java, linux, docker

New to linux and working on containerizing our stack and essentially here is the problem that I am running into with the code below:

a) I have to execute this dockerfile as a non-root user for elastic search to work (requirement)

b)If I add `USER $USERNAME` to the bottom of the script before CMD i get the error:
"mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
Can not write to /root/.m2/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions? Carrying on"

c) If I remove the `USER $USERNAME` from the bottom of the file then I get the elastic search issue referenced above.

What I am asking is, how can I fix this in my dockerfile?

```
# Custom image from Maven on DockerHub
# Language: dockerfile
FROM maven:3.6.3-amazoncorretto-8

# Set the working dir
WORKDIR /app

# Create a non root user
ARG USERNAME=jefferson
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Add linux dependenciesq
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN yum install shadow-utils -y

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && yum install sudo -y \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 777 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && sudo groupadd docker \
    && sudo usermod -aG docker $USERNAME \
    && newgrp docker 

# Change to the root folder and edit the settings.xml for Maven
WORKDIR /root/.m2
RUN rm -rf settings.xml
RUN echo '<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" \
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 \
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> \
</settings>' >> settings.xml

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

USER $USERNAME

# Run the application
CMD ["mvn", "clean", "verify", "-Pcargo.run", "-X"]
```

Comment: `chmod 777 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME` Congratulations, your non-root user is effectively root now :)

Comment: "execute this dockerfile as a non-root user": What do you mean with this? Execute the container? Execute something in the container?

Comment: Do you actually need to run `mvn clean` when you run the container?  If you delete "clean" from the `CMD` and only run `mvn verify` does it work better?  If this is just running unit tests, can you run them from outside Docker?

Comment: @tobias this means to create the entire dir `app/` as a root user having permissions to edit the root dir to edit `settings.xml` and then before running the CMD to run the application, logging into a newly created non-root user to run the application but with root permissions (writeable, editable, executable). Is this possible? The solution provided with code did not work as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidMaze unfortunately that is the series of commands I have to use and we do have to include testing to pass in docker as part of build safety.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand well your needs, on the official docker maven image give you have a way to follow :

Why not fully use a non-root user to run maven (and not trying to write in the root directory) ?

at this page : https://hub.docker.com/_/maven under the header named

> Running as non-root

it tells you to use a *MAVEN_CONFIG* env var and to add the *-Duser.home=* flag when calling maven to run maven without using the root user

here is the full Dockerfile modified using this way (from your own Dockerfile):

```
# Custom image from Maven on DockerHub
# Language: dockerfile
FROM maven:3.6.3-amazoncorretto-8

# Set the working dir
WORKDIR /app

# Create a non root user
ARG USERNAME=jefferson
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Add linux dependenciesq
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN yum install shadow-utils -y

ENV MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && yum install sudo -y \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 600 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && sudo groupadd docker \
    && sudo usermod -aG docker $USERNAME \
    && newgrp docker 

# Change to the root folder and edit the settings.xml for Maven
WORKDIR "/var/maven/.m2"
RUN rm -rf settings.xml \
    && chown $USER_UID:$USER_GID .
RUN echo '<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" \
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 \
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> \
</settings>' >> settings.xml

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

USER $USERNAME

# Run the application
CMD ["mvn", "clean", "verify", "-Duser.home=/var/maven", "-Pcargo.run", "-X"]
```

the rights of the sudoers file you added was too permissive so i changed it to 600.

*as an example :*

with the following command line (**you don't** have to run this command line in your case because the example command line given (on the maven docker image site) is just starting a new container with interactive mode and mounting volumes)

> docker run -v ~/.m2:/var/maven/.m2 -ti --rm -u 1000 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2 maven mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven archetype:generate

Comment: I do not understand how this command `docker run -v ~/.m2:/var/maven/.m2 -ti --rm -u 1000 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2 maven mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven archetype:generate` will create and run a docker container from the docker file that I have specified. How does this even work? Your code did not work for me btw.

Comment: @Cody Wirth, the example command line given (on the maven docker image site) is just starting a new container (with interactive mode) mounting volumes, the important thing in your case is that this command line show you how to use maven the recommended way if you do not use the root ``user``. this is by using ``-u 1000``, the environment variable ``MAVEN_CONFIG`` and the mvn flag ``-Duser.home=``. i will adjust the first answer for this to be more clear.

Comment: @CodyWirth, if you have any error message, you can share it for help in the comments, see you

Comment: is achetype:generate the dockerfile and tagged image?

Comment: Ok @Chikung here is the error after doing everything you have said, and using the command provided to run my newly built imageL

Comment: "No plugin found for prefix 'paige-back' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/var/maven/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]"

Comment: ``archetype:generate`` is only a maven parameter used in the exemple. The error you quote seems to me like a maven problem, the maven local repository with non-root user is like working !?